# Laravel autocomplete search doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I created a search field in my laravel project inside my products.blade . My ajax also inside that page. However its doesn't work , the autocomplete not responding , if I push search button its refreshes the page and stays the same.

My route is:

```
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@index'));
Route::get('searchajax',array('as'=>'searchajax','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@autoComplete'));
```

My AutoCompleteController is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
class AutoCompleteController extends MainController {

    public function index(){
        return view('content.products');
   }
    public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
        $query = $request->get('term','');

        $products=Product::where('title','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();

        $data=array();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$product->title,'id'=>$product->id);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }

}
```

My products.blade  view:

```
@extends ('master') 

@section('content')  
<div class="row">  
    <form class="navbar-form text-center " form method="GET" action=" ">
        <input id="search_text" placeholder=" Search products" name="search_text" type="text" value="" style="width: 400px; height: 35px; border-radius: 5px ; padding-left: 12px;"><br><br>
        <input class="btn btn-default " type="submit" value="  Search" > 
    </form> 
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {

     $("#search_text").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchajax') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So.. what in your route matches `url('shop')`?  Did you check for Javascript errors as I'm sure you would have had a 404 or something else in your console.

Comment: @Devon I changed it to url: "{{ route('searchajax') }}"...is that more correct?If I look inside mu console I got this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at action-figures:89" . action-figures is one of my categories

Comment: Usually means jquery hasn't been loaded

Comment: @Devon all my jquery is in my Master . My view extends my Master. I have the regular jquery and jquery ui. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Well, search for the primary portion of the error message on here and I'm sure you'll find plenty of resources.